# Psycopg2 query returning today's date

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to run a query through psycopg2 that selects a line of data depending on today's date. How do I use % to accomplish this?

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt
import psycopg2

hostname = '###'
username = '###'
password = '###'
database = '###'

# Run psql query and print results
def doQuery(conn):
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute( "select * from  getsimplebookevents_psx(%s,'{CSCO}') 
order by tstamp desc limit 1;")

for symbol in cur.fetchall():
  print symbol
```

Comment: There's nothing in that python code select statement that depends on today's date. However, there's a way to get the current date in postgres, so maybe you can do something like `SELECT * from some_table WHERE tstamp > current_date()`

Comment: does `getsimplebookevents_psx` expect `timestamptz` or `timestamp`?..